# Calculate eigenvalues and eigenvector for given 4x4 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all the eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors for the given matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}5 &1 &-1& 0\\0 & 2 &0 &3\\ 0 & 0 &2 &1 \\0 & 0 &0 &3\end{bmatrix}$

So I went about finding the determinant by writing (5-$\lambda$) $\begin{bmatrix}2 &0 &-3\\0 & 2 &1 \\ 0 & 0 &3\\\end{bmatrix}$ Then I calculated the 3x3 determinant to be (5-$\lambda$)+2(6+0) and got the 17-$\lambda$ is this correct? Also where do I plug in this eigenvalue of 17 to find the eigenvector?

Answer (score 2):

Where does the eigenvalue $17$ come from? Keep going by expanding the determinant and in that way, keep factoring.

The matrix is in [upper triangular form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) and that's good news, because the determinant is then just the product of the diagonal elements! So:
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}5-\lambda &1 &-1& 0\\0 & 2-\lambda &0 &3\\ 0 & 0 &2-\lambda &1 \\0 & 0 &0 &3-\lambda\end{bmatrix} = (5-\lambda)(2-\lambda)^2(3-\lambda)$$
This means the eigenvalues are $5$, $2$ and $3$.

For each of the eigenvalues, plug back in and solve the associated homogeneous system of equations. For $\lambda = 5$, solve:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 &1 &-1& 0\\0 & -3 &0 &3\\ 0 & 0 &-3 &1 \\0 & 0 &0 &-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix} $$
From the last equation ($-2x_4 = 0$), it is clear that $x_4 = 0$. Substitute into the third equation to get $x_3=0$ and in the second to get $x_2=0$. From the first equation, $x_1$ remains as a free variable so vectors of the form $(x_1,0,0,0)$ are eigenvectors associated with the eigenvalue $5$; pick e.g. $(1,0,0,0)$.

Do the same for the other eigenvalues. Can you take it from here?

Comment: ah makes sense! Idk how I really got 17 to be honest but I just knew it was really wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @Lil If you stare at that first matrix equation long enough, you should be able to convince yourself that the eigenvalues of a triangular matrix *are* its diagonal entries.